# how to clear all filters for devexpress dx-react-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress, devextreme

I have a basic table using the devexpress/dx-react-grid library. I am trying to clear all of the column filters but I cannot find a method in the documents. I see some examples that could possibly do what I need but it seems like there would be a simple way of doing this.

```
<Grid rows={_data} columns={COLUMNS}>
      <FilteringState
        changeColumnFilter
        onFiltersChange={val => { this._filters = val }}
        defaultFilters={[]}
      />
      <SelectionState
        selection={_selection}
        onSelectionChange={this.props.setSelection}
      />
      <IntegratedSelection />
      <IntegratedFiltering />
      <SortingState />
      <IntegratedSorting />
      <VirtualTable height={_windowHeight - 286} cellComponent={Cell} />
      <TableHeaderRow showSortingControls />
      <TableSelection showSelectAll />
      <TableFilterRow />
    </Grid>
```

I am using @devexpress/dx-react-grid 1.2.0